# Extract a particular column from a csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a .csv file in the following format:

```
ID1    ID2    city       Country
AR     xyz    Tokyo      Japan
AR            New York   USA
AR     abc    Vienna     Austria
```

I want to extract the third column data from the file using a regular expression so the output would be:

```
Tokyo
New York
Vienna
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a `csv` file?  The "c" stands for comma, and there aren't any commas.  Sometimes people use it to mean "delimiter-separated", and to include semicolons and tabs, but your data doesn't seem to be separated by that either.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [csv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module? This can be much faster.

```
import csv

with open('this.file') as this_file:
  source = csv.reader(this_file, delimiter=' ')
  next(source)  # skipping header
  for row in source:
    print(row[3])
```

Comment: `next(source)` instead of `source.next()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid sorry, tested that on 2.7...

Comment: should use `with open('this.file', 'rb') as f`.

Comment: @ErikAllik I think it's better to keep example as simple as possible without throwing in all python goodness at once.

Comment: `with open(...) as f:` is idiomatic Python, not some special goodness; besides, `open()` without a `.close()` of any sort is simply bad practice.

Comment: oh, I've mean impling 'rb' to just any other file without looking into encodings.

Comment: If the OP is using Python 2.7, then the correct way to open a `csv` file is using `open('this.file', 'rb')`.  If the OP is using Python 3, then it should be `open('this.file', 'r', newline='')`.  I'm also a little worried about the delimiters-- if they're spaces, won't using `" "` as the delimiter break `New York` into two parts?

Comment: -1 This answer is broken because csv module is expecting one and only one space for delimiter in the data

Comment: @wim No way I would fix it, the script was given just to show how the module can be used. It surely would give bad results on given data because of "New York" and absence of value in the third row. But this just rises a question whether this all was about CSV or not. Besides, we both can be wrong as if creator was pasting data from the console the tabs can become spaces and format would be ruined.

Comment: Exactly.  The data is not CSV, so this answer is useless (if you actually ran it you would see that it just prints a bunch of empty strings).

Comment: The anwser is useless because question about CSV data includes sample of non-CSV data.